# How to show onTabSelected?

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

When I click Button from FirstActivity, it go to SecondActivity and selected Tag 5. But on screen (fragment) is shown Tag 1. why? I use **it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost** library

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
    pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `TabLayout` ? Just use them

Comment: So, I can't solve this problem by using MaterialTabHost.?

Comment: I'll have to see this lib then.